Why does OpenCV cv2.imshow freeze after closing the window manually on Ubuntu?
I am working with OpenCV to display an image, and I encountered a problem on Ubuntu. The code works fine when I press the ESC key to exit the window, but if I manually click the "X" button to close the window, the program hangs and doesn't proceed to the next steps (e.g., saving the image).
Here is my code:
import cv2

path = "/home/huanyizhiyuan/Softwares/VsCode_workspace/Python_workspace/image_solve/card1.jpg"

# Read the image
img = cv2.imread(path)
if img is None:
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"Image not found: {path}")

# Resize the image
img = cv2.resize(img, (1000, 800))

# Display the image
cv2.imshow('image', img)

# Wait for keyboard input
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Close the window
cv2.destroyWindow('image')

# Save the image
cv2.imwrite('new_image.jpg', img)



If I press ESC or any key while the window is open, the program exits as expected, and the image is saved correctly.

If I manually click the close button (the "X" button in the corner of the window), the program freezes. It does not save the image or exit gracefully.



Environment:
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
opencv-python: 4.10.0.84
Python: 3.12.7

What I’ve Tried:

I checked if the image path was correct and verified that the image is being displayed properly.
I attempted to use cv2.destroyWindow after cv2.waitKey(0), but the issue persists when clicking the close button.


print(cv.getBuildInformation()), the GUI section, what does it say? I'd like to know the GUI toolkit that is being used by OpenCV on your system

waitKey is supposed to return (with -1) if there are no more open windows, regardless of how they were closed. this could be a bug in the part of OpenCV's highgui that's active on your system.

My hunch its with compatibility across different systems. As you are using linux modify like this
while True:
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == 27 or cv2.getWindowProperty('image', cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) < 1:
        break

In a single Picture
import cv2

path = "/home/huanyizhiyuan/Softwares/VsCode_workspace/Python_workspace/image_solve/card1.jpg"

# Read the image
img = cv2.imread(path)
if img is None:
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"Image not found: {path}")

# Resize the image
img = cv2.resize(img, (1000, 800))

# Display the image
cv2.imshow('image', img)

# Wait for key event or window close
while True:
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == 27 or cv2.getWindowProperty('image', cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) < 1:
        break

# Close the window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Save the image
cv2.imwrite('new_image.jpg', img)

The & 0xFF is used to extract the last 8 bits of the key code, which can help with compatibility across different systems
Have a look - What's 0xFF for in cv2.waitKey(1)?


Why does OpenCV cv2.imshow freeze after closing the window manually on
Ubuntu?

The problem can be fixed.
You must include another cv2.imshow since you are using cv2.destroyWindow('image').
Snippet:
# Display the image
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('image_1', img)

This will close button (the "X" button in the corner of the window). One at a time.

nope, that's not fixing the issue.

You should file a bug about this on OpenCV's Github.
Your situation probably comes from waitKey() not returning even though all windows are gone now. It's unlikely to stem from destroyWindow() crashing (that would have terminated the process).
